# Concatenating two dataframes resulting in empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataB which I want to append to my dataframe dataA when a certain condition is fulfilled. This should be really easy but I'm getting an empty result at the end (I can make it work with 'append' but I read it's deprecated. Below is my code:

-I read dataB from file
-create dataA dataframe with same keys
-Loop through dataB and when condition is met, I get the row and 'append' it to dataA. Using concat, this does not work.

```
dataB= pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")
keys = bondData.keys()
dataA= pd.DataFrame(columns=keys)



for i in range(0,len(dataB)):
    if dataB['Coupon'][i] == 0:
        pd.concat([dataA,dataB.iloc[i]])
```

I get this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Ttm, Cusip, ISIN, Full_ISIN, Coupon, Issue Date, Des, YTM]
Index: []
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are just trying to filter `dataB` only keeping the rows where Coupon is zero. You do *not* use a loop for that. Instead, use any of the selection methods pandas provides, e.g. `loc`, `query`

For example: `dataA = dataB.query("Coupon == 0")`

---

Using your original approach, in addition to the missing assignment to `dataA` as pointed out in Alonso's answer, you need to make sure that you concatenate DataFrames in order to preserve the columns. `dataB.iloc[i]` selects a single row as a series. You can use `dataB.iloc[[i]]` to select a single row as a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

dataB = pd.DataFrame({'Coupon': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                      'year': [2003,2004,2005, 2003, 2004, 2004]})

keys = dataB.keys()
dataA= pd.DataFrame(columns=keys)

for i in range(0,len(dataB)):
    if dataB['Coupon'][i] == 0:
        dataA = pd.concat([dataA, dataB.iloc[[i]]])

print(dataA)

#result:
  Coupon  year
0      0  2003
1      0  2004
2      0  2005
```

Comment: Hi mcsoini, thank you. You are indeed right however I will also be doing other stuff when Coupon is not zero, so I think it still makes sense to loop through everything, you see my point?

Comment: I updated the answer to provide a fix to your original problem. Depending on what that other stuff is (e.g. not pandas related), I would still first filter the dataframe and the loop over the new rows. Looping over pandas rows for table operations is virtually never a thing.

Comment: Hi mcsoini, thank you for pointing the mistake :) I am deleting my solution :)

Comment: That's interesting. So even after filtering my data, you say I should NOT loop over the new rows? What would you advise then? For example, when coupon is not zero, I want to go calculate all coupon dates and put them all in DataB. I believe looping would be perfect for this, because I am doing different 'stuff' for each row. Right?

Comment: I suggest you define a minimum reproducible example for this, using some toy data (as I did in my answer) and post another question. It depends on how you calculate the coupon dates, but I strongly assume a loop is not a good approach.